# Система накопления знаний

Tags: php

Привет!
Хотелось бы узнать кто какими способами сохраняет полученные знания?

Со временем накапливается очень много информации, какие-то заготовки, шаблоны. Все это в голове держать просто невозможно да и не нужно. Для текстовой информации использую Evernote, но вот куски кода там хранить ну совсем не удобно. Поэтому ищу более удобное решение.

Расскажите о своем опыте.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

svn/git/jsfiddle/pastebin первое, что на ум пришло.

ps; да и еще можно всякие сервисы типа dropbox, google drive, google source code, bitbucket....

удобно, "секурно", доступно из любого места, где есть интернет. живет независимо от взрыва вашего компьютера :)

Answer (score 4):

Лучше всего хранить наработки в готовых проектах. Таким образом они доводятся до ума, а не пропадают в дебрях небытия.

Если не хотите похоронить свои эксперименты - создавайте работающий проектик с вашими фичами.

Comment: Да, можно в проектах. Но не всегда помнишь, что и где использовал. Хочется иметь централизованное хранилище с заметками, кодом и прочим. Наверное сделать себе сайт самый простой вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Я вот создал папку PHP, а внутри нее создаю папки по каждой теме.Сохраняю страничку в браузере и перемещаю туда.Жаль что раньше так не делал.

Answer (score 1):

куски кода?? можно в снипетах... редактор PHP Designer
большие куски кода на GitHub, можно даже закоммитить.
Такой ресурс как GitHub можно по разному использовать, лишь бы толк был :)

Answer (score 1):

Читайте сабж внимательней. Автор говорит о "хранении знаний", а вы все сводите к хранению кода. У меня та же проблема была и есть.
А знания это например также программные ошибки и способы их устранения; готовые модули в связке из неск файлов (js+php+ajax+..., чего не уместишь на одну страничку в textarea); выжимки из интересных статей; идеи по кодингу. В общем, гораздо более емкое чем сниппет-хранилища коих тучи.
.
И я ничо подобного не нашел! 
Под это дело вяло подходит Evernote (с его удобным поиском и мета-тегами), но он у меня забит бытовыми заметками и не хочется смешивать раз и два - это всетаки не проф. инструмент и нет возможности его под себя улучшить.
...
Вывод - разработать что-то свое на php том же, хранить в файлах и в БД данные. С редкатором онлайн, с подсветкой кода, поиском и др фичами.
Если за мой коммент проголосуют, сделаю для себя а потом зарелизю для публичного использования ) Силы/знания есть, нужно только время потратить, но бета-версию можно за день написать вполне.